# Intermittent delays in query execution in Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, amazon-rds

We are developing an `ASP.NET 5` based WebAPI hosted on Amazon AWS Kubernates pods (usually up to 4 pods spinning at the same time).  As a primary database we use RDS instance of `SQL Server 2016` to which we connect using  `EF core 5.0.4`.

We are experiencing a major performance degradation when executing SQL server queries with Entity Framework. Those issues seems intermittent, but SQL Profiling shows query performance with an average duration below `50ms`, when queries from within the application can run longer than a couple of seconds.  We recently upgraded the SQL instance to L but the upgrade did not bring any performance improvement.

Queries we run are usually quite complex, but the data load is very low for the sql server that size.

In addition:

1. All database calls are awaited
2. Recently added MARS con string parameter seems to brought some performance improvement (but really hard to tell).

`Server= xxxxx,1433;Database=xxxxx;user id=xxxx;password=xxxxx;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

3. We compose queries through a generic repository:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TModel> GetQueryable<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IOrderedQueryable<TModel>> orderBy = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IQueryable<TModel>> includeProperties = null,
            int? skip = null,
            int? take = null,
            bool noTracking = false
            ) where TModel : class, TDto
        {
            var query = context.Set<TModel>().AsQueryable();

            if (noTracking)
                query = query.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                query = includeProperties(query);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            if (skip.HasValue && skip != 0)
            {
                query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
            }

            if (take.HasValue && take != int.MaxValue)
            {
                query = query.Take(take.Value);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

Is there any way to actually see what might cause the slowness? It there a way to track the transportation cost? Could it be the roundtip to RDS would be to blame?

Comment: the code looks simple except that the `includeProperties` may include a lot of related data. I would inspect the generated sql to try it directly and see if we can improve it (as well as to know why it's slow).

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities. If query is too complex EF can slowdown query because of its slow query translator. You have shown some generic repository but not slow query. Try to mark them with `WithTag` and find which query is not performant.

Comment: All included entities are in fact eager loaded. The query itself is not a problem. We experience the slowness on different queries. All of them perform instantly when debugging with SQL profiler.

Comment: So show slow query, or try to run .NET profiler and check what happened.

Comment: Please read the question. All information are in there, including the fact I run the query profiler which show the duration for the query at around 50ms.

Comment: Not query profiler. BUT .NET Profiler, `dotTrace` for example. EF Core LINQ translation can be slow, but it has caching. So run this query twice second run should be fast.

Comment: Thanks for this will defo try, although that could potentialy explain delegradation in selects only, but the create or update queries are affected as well. Insights profiler show quite disturbing ASYNC_IO_NETWORK stats which indicates that either application or network might a  bottleneck here. Wonder how to exclude one from the equation.